# Mac OS: "Minimize" vs "Hide" - what's the difference?

Tags: macos, mac

Why does OS X have both a "Hide" and a "Minimize" feature?  This seems somewhat redundant to me, and also introduces some inconsistency when I am trying to find an arbitrary window.  If it's hidden, I need to activate the application and use the "Windows" menu to bring it up; if the window is minimized, it appears in the dock.

What are some scenarios in which you'd use these two features differently?

Comment: This is the one feature that confuses me the most and I miss Windows every time :(

Answer (score 33, accepted):

"Minimize" minimizes the program to the dock where you can see a thumbnail of the program's window.

"Hide" hides the window without adding the program's thumbnail to the dock.

I will minimize a program if I need to get it out of the way for a few moments while I'll hide a program if I need it out of the way for an extended period of time.  Most of the time I will hide icons.

Comment: When I hide my app, it still appears in the dock. Why?

Comment: It appears in the Dock, but only the icon appears. If you minimize it, there's also a small icon representing the window on the right side, next to the Trash.

Comment: You can set Snow Leopard to combine the two options as a minimize to item setting on the dock.

Comment: Minimize minimizes a *single* window. Hide hides the *entire* application.

Comment: The dock shows you running APPLICATIONS, and then shows or lists the applications windows when you click or click and hold, respectively.  It is NOT a window list, like in Windows XP.  I think it's much more logical.  Also, interestingly, Windows 7 seems to be attempting to copy this idea.

Comment: You may also use [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) to make the icon in the Dock slightly opaque when an application is hidden.  I've found that it's really helpful to my workflow.

Comment: A minimized window does not maximize when you select its application in the app switcher (`cmd+tab`). However, **all** windows of a hidden application _will_ reappear when selecting it with the app switcher.

Answer (score 35):

To start, there are cosmetic differences: **Minimize** does a little graphic effect and puts a shrunken icon of the window into your Dock (on the right hand side, not with the apps, although this can be changed).  **Hide** makes all of the application's windows simply disappear from view without any changes to the Dock.

But the big difference lies in how you make the windows reappear.

- **Minimized windows require a mouse click** in the Dock to summon them.
- **Hidden** apps will reappear if you Command-Tab to the app, so you can bring back the windows **using the keyboard only.**

  *(You can also click in the Dock to get a hidden app back.)*

Because I use Command-Tab heavily, and try to avoid the mouse, I use "Hide" quite a bit but never use "Mimimize" as it *requires* mouse interaction to get the window back.

As others have noted, you can set the Dock preferences to "minimize into application icon".  This doesn't change the keyboard/mouse equation; all it does is prevent a "minimized" window from getting its own icon in the Dock - instead you have to click on the app icon in the dock to un-minimize the window.

Comment: As there are menu items for all windows in the application's *Window* menu, they can be restored by using the keyboard only. It might be a bit more work though.

Comment: @DanielBeck - how?  Those window entries don't necessarily have a hotkey associated with them.  You can't create a hotkey, either, as the windows will have varying names (eg, in Firefox, it's the name of the active tab), and hotkeys created via Preferences > Keyboard have to match the name of the menu option exactly.  Is there a way to keyboard through OS X menus that I'm not aware of?

Comment: You can type the window name into the search box usually accessible via `Cmd-?` (*System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Application Shortcuts » Show Help menu*), and you can use the keyboard to navigate the menu bar by pressing `Ctrl-F2` (or whatever shortcut is assigned in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Keyboard and Text Input » Move focus to the menu bar*). As I said, it's possible, but a bit more work. Some applications also have no (or not only) dynamic window titles and may even assign default keyboard shortcuts (iTunes, Things, ...).

Comment: You could also use Witch to get customizable window switching menus and shortcuts ("Deminimize all minimized windows", "Cycle through frontmost application's minimized windows", etc.). I only use it to get a keyboard shortcut for the zoom window button, but it's capable of a lot more.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the Ctl-F2 bit - I didn't know that shortcut.  Bringing "Witch" into the picture of course changes the answer, as third party tools will let you configure all sorts of things.

Comment: You can always open minimized app with cmd+tab (before release cmd, hold option)

Comment: Thanks.  Coming from Windows, the point about how windows re-appear is critical.  It has taken me a good long while to figure out the difference between minimize and hide -- honestly it seems terribly overcomplicated.  One could say it's a Windows bias, but Ubuntu doesn't behave this way either.

Comment: A slightly more visual and selective method to open minimized windows using the keyboard (alternative to Cmd + Tab and holding Option before releasing Cmd): use Cmd + Tab to switch to the hidden app, release Cmd, press Ctrl + Down to view all of the now-active-but-minimized app's windows that appear as very small preview images at the bottom of the space, release Ctrl, arrow to the previewed window you want to open, and hit Return to open it. Source: [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236#:~:text=control%E2%80%93down%20arrow%3A%20show%20all%20windows%20of%20the%20front%20app).

Comment: You could also use AltTab (https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/) which will always display minimized window and bring them back without having to do something else than a simple Cmd+Tab.

Comment: @Eddie Thanks for the information, btw is there a hotkey for bring back an another minimized window of current app? `command+\``seems not work.

Answer (score 14):

Hiding will remove the application from view (while still being visible in the application switcher and dock).

Minimizing will minimize a single window to the dock, not the entire application.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the answer @Rich Bradshaw gave in the comments to an official answer, since it's exactly what I was looking for.

> You can set Snow Leopard to combine
>   the two options as a minimize to item
>   setting on the dock.

Comment: For the record, this option is available in the "Dock" System Preferences applet, labeled "Minimize windows into application icon".